# Retrieve variables Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way of retrieving a pattern inside a regular expression in Python? eg.:

strA = '\ta -- b'

and I would like to retrieve 'a' and 'b' into different variables

Comment: without using split() method, because the pattern of string can vary

Comment: `(?<=\\t)(\w+\b).*?(\b\w+\b)` (example: http://regex101.com/r/fW1fV7/1)

Comment: Please describe how the pattern varies (otherwise a regex may not match all possibilities)

Comment: What separates patterns in the regex?  Will your first variable always follow `\t`? Will the two always be separated by ` -- `? Will there be multiple patterns within the string, or will there only ever be 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about [saving/capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r"\t(\w+) -- (\w+)"
>>> s = '       test1 -- test2'
>>> a, b = re.search(pattern, s).groups()
>>> a
'test1'
>>> b
'test2'
```

Comment: Should `\t` be `\\t` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve a **pattern**, you can match or retrieve a **capturing group content** matching your pattern.

Following your example:

```
\ta -- b
```

If you want to retrieve the content you can use capturing groups using parentheses like:

```
\t(a) -- (b)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The regex explanation for this is:

```
\t                       '\t' (tab)
(                        group and capture to \1:
  a                        'a'
)                        end of \1
 --                      ' -- '
(                        group and capture to \2:
  b                        'b'
)                        end of \2
```

Then you would be able to grab group content by accesing then through its index like `\1` (or `$1`) and group `\2` (or `$2`). But you are going to grab the matched content, not the pattern itself.

So, if you have:

```
\t(\w) -- (\d)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You would grab content that matches that pattern:

```
\t                       '\t' (tab)
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
)                        end of \1
 --                      ' -- '
(                        group and capture to \2:
  \d                       digits (0-9)
)                        end of \2
```

But you can't retrieve `\w` or `\d` itself.

If you want to get the patterns for this:

```
\t\w -- \d
```

You should split above string by `--` and you would get strings::

```
"\t\w "
" \d"
```